# Snowflake SQL: How to add a time to a date to make a datetime?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

I have a date column and a time column and I'd like to make a datetime/timestamp.

I've tried

```
Date+Time
```

but I get:

> SQL compilation error: error line 4 at position 14 Invalid argument types for function '+': (DATE, TIME(9))

Comment: Can you specify which implementation of SQL this is using (mysql, postgres, SQL Server)?

Comment: @v25 snowflake, as per tags.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [TIMESTAMP_NTZ_FROM_PARTS(date, time)](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/timestamp_from_parts.html), e.g.

```
select timestamp_ntz_from_parts('2013-04-05'::date, '01:02:03.12345'::time);
----------------------------------------------------------------------+
 TIMESTAMP_NTZ_FROM_PARTS('2013-04-05'::DATE, '01:02:03.12345'::TIME) |
----------------------------------------------------------------------+
 2013-04-05 01:02:03.123450000                                        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```